# didFinishProcessingPhoto Executes only 10 times in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am building an app that captures many images and stores it in an array but i am having problem that my `didFinishProcessingPhoto` only executes 10 times while my for loop is of 20.

My code:-

```
  func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    guard let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation(),
        let image =  UIImage(data: data)  else {
            return
    }

    self.img.image = image
    self.imgs.append(image)
}
@IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    for i in 0 ... 20 {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you positive it's only running 10 times or is it possible it's only succeeding 10 times out of 20? put print(i) in your for loop

Comment: yaa my for loop is executing 20 times but didfinishprocessingphoto method only executes 10 times it only gives 10 photos in my array

Comment: it's likely that youre running it too fast, the video is likely moving at 30 or 60 hz and your hitting the AVCapture session far too fast that it can't keep up. Try a quick test with usleep(100000) in your for loop. This will capture images at 10hz, you can adjust the timing once you have it working

Comment: @JustinMiller not working

Comment: Did it work any more or any less than the 10 time previously?

Comment: @JustinMiller No effect